# Weird Empty Space in the bottom of the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

The `contentSize` of the table view is about 20 higher than the frame. 
It should be the same as the frame since I've already turn down all related stuff.

I got three rows in the one and only section. Each row's height is 46.
So the height in total should be 46*3=138. But it's not.

It really confused me a lot.
The section header and footer are both 0.001.
The table view is inherited from the `MATableView` whose initializer is as the following.

```
class MATableView: UITableView {a

    init(frame: CGRect, presentOn object: AnyObject) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: .grouped)
        delegate = (object as! UITableViewDelegate)
        dataSource = (object as! UITableViewDataSource)
        bounces = false
        backgroundColor = .white
        separatorStyle = .none
        tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0.01))
        tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0.01))
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        estimatedRowHeight = 0
        estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
        estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

    // In the delegate controller 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.001
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.001
    }
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Replace `heightForFooterInSection` && `heightForHeaderInSection` height from `0.001` to `1.1` and try

Comment: try returning nil for func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?

Comment: @Pankil It's not working. This value should work if larger than 0.

Comment: @koropok It's working!

Comment: @koropok Plz write it as the answer. BTW, my propose can be simply done by set tableView's `sectionHeaderHeight` and `sectionFooterHeight` to `0`. I missed those two lines when copied the code from earlier version.

Comment: @JsW ok will write it as the answer, thanks!

Comment: why you use header and footer while you have to return nil.

Comment: @mnemonic23 The header and footer could be used depends on the some status fetched from the server. I just post a example. Sorry for making a confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return nil for viewForHeaderInSection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You estimated heights should be greater than 0. Set them nearby approx values.

Comment: Set it to 0 means to turn off the estimation. Because I don't need a footer or header :P

Answer (score 0):

It would be done quickly and simply by just setting `sectionHeaderHeight` and `sectionFooterHeight` to `0`.

```
init(frame: CGRect, presentOn object: AnyObject) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: .grouped)
        ...
        sectionHeaderHeight = 0
        sectionFooterHeight = 0
        ...
    }
```